# Commenting line that is never executed leads to crash

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, compilation, linker

I am a bit lost and have a strange situation. Here some information about the setup

- iOS app with several frameworks of static and dynamic nature
- mainThread plus audioThread to process incoming buffer

Then I have a framework that is linked but not used. So the code inside this framework is actually never executed (but supposed to in the future). Now when I comment out a specific line inside the framework (that is never executed) this leads to a crash inside the audio thread.

Thats the crash `exc_bad_access (code=2)`

And maybe it helps, thats the line commented out inside a `.cpp` file `tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;`

Now my generic question is. What could a the reasons for this? The simple fact that code is compiled leads to changed behaviour in completely unrelated parts or the app?

#### Update 1

The BuiltinOpResolver seems to be this (i have a prebuilt framework here, not including the source directly) https://github.com/rockchip-linux/tensorflow/blob/e1877bb157a775d76ec8c0b68467aef6d053bbb2/tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/register.cc

Comment: What happens in the constructor of `BuiltinOpResolver`?

Comment: There is also [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28345).

Comment: please consider posting your code here, providing code outside of SO is consider not good practice --> [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When your code has undefined behaviour then just moving code around in memory can be the difference between a crash and working.

Comment: @john this sounds very valid. When changing code and trying to get closer to the cause i see that it crashes on different threads in different regions of the app. Whats the approach to find out the cause?

Comment: @MartinMlostek I would try eliminating sections of code. If the errors go away then there's a good chance that the eliminated code contained the error. Use this approach to try and narrow down to a small a section of code as possible. The problem is that you have multiple threads, so getting consistent results might be tricky.

Comment: @john thanks. Can it be the just the fact that another library is linked leads to a problem that was already there (e.g. threading issue) but it was not leading to crashes before?

Comment: @MartinMlostek It's possible.

Comment: There are many possibilities and, without representative code, nobody can help you.  Undefined behaviour can result in jumps to execute apparently unreachable code - that's one reason of several that safety-critical development encourages removal of "dead code" (aka code that is not expected to be executed) to ensure no artifacts of it remain in an executable and able to be accidentally executed.    More common, however, is that there is a path of execution in your program that you are not aware of, that causes the code to be executed even though you believe it is unreachable.

Comment: Whenever you see this sort of unaccountable error, it's a good idea to try running the same scenario using the Address Sanitizer and the Undefined Behavior sanitizer.  These are available in the Diagnostics tab of the Run Scheme in Xcode.  The Address sanitizer works by instrumenting code, so you'll probably want to build the tensorflow code locally with ASAN turned on for that build as well.

Comment: @JimIngham do you have an idea how to set those flags within a make file?

Comment: It's mostly passing `-fsanitize=address`, but there are some other options too. I'd just make a simple C++ CommandLine project in Xcode, build it both ways see how the compile & link lines changed.  The simplest way to see the full compiler & linker invocations for a project in Xcode is to use Terminal, cd to the directory with the Xcode project and run `xcodebuild -configuration Debug`, then run it again like: `xcodebuild -configuration Debug ---enableAddressSanitizer YES`.  There are also flags for UBSAN& TSAN.